# Latex equations in MS Word

Tags: msword

I have tried to write equations using Latex in Microsoft Word by following the steps given in this [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8). However, when the Latex code is changed into professional format, additional codes are added into my equation by the editor. For example, the code

```
\cos(\Delta k_{21}r)=-1
```

will be changed into

```
\cos\left(\Delta k_{21}r\right)=-1
```

As such, the brackets become larger than what would be expected. How can this be solved? Hope you can help.

BTW, is this problem a limitation of MS Word? Do you recommend using another plugin in word, such as wordTex? At the moment, I am not able to switch to other editors.

Comment: Hi, you may use MathType as the MS Word extension which supports LaTeX syntax fairly well. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with macOS with Apple Silicon; and it is not free software.